# How to get return from Postgresql Function with EF in Dotnet Core

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql, sql-function

I am trying to using functions and stored procedures in postgresql using by EF core. I created a function by writing ef migration file and updated my database. I can see my function is created on db and when I run "select public.sp_Get_Products()" in Pgadmin i get my result correctly.

But when i try to get the results by EF core the code belows return to me: -1

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select public.sp_Get_Products()");
```

If I try to use FromSqlRaw below, it returns The required column 'Id' was not present in the result of a 'FromSql' operation

```
_context.Product.FromSqlRaw("select public.sp_Get_Products()");
```

So i still counldnt find a way to get my select result from postgresql by function.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteSqlCommand` is only for executing commands that don't return results.

`FromSqlRaw` is for executing arbitrary SQL that returns data that has the exact same shape as an entity in your model, so it's your responsibility to make sure that `sp_Get_Products` returns all the fields in Product. It would seem like your function may not be returning the `Id` column.